# Will using a tool change the quality of an item?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a Genuine [Ham Shank](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Ham_Shank) from pre-ordering Don't Starve on Steam:

[image: picture of quality]

I'd like to know what would happen if:

- I applied [paint](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Paint_Can) to my Ham Shank
  *and/or*
- I used a [Name Tag](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Name_tag) to change the item's name

Will it keep the green text indicating it is an item of genuine quailty if I apply one or both of the above tools (or any other tools such as the [Description Tag](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Description_Tag) for that matter)?

Comment: What do  you mean by adding "paint"? You can't add paint to weapons at all (with the exception of some very rare CM5Ks)

Comment: The question was more what happens to the quality, if it pleases you pretend everywhere I said "Ham Shank" is replaced with "Wilson Weave" (A hat I have from the same pre-order on steam).  Good catch though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qualities (Genuine, Unusual, Strange, etc.) are independent of modifications made by tools such as paint and name tags and cannot ever be changed. (Unless you count the [Strange Bacon Grease](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Bacon_Grease), which probably takes away the original item and gives a strange one.)

If you *rename* an item, the name will still be displayed **in the color for its quality**, but the quality will not be added to the name you choose. For example, if you rename your “Genuine Ham Shank” to “Squishy Club”, its name will not be “Genuine Squishy Club”, but just “Squishy Club” (in green text).

Notably, renamed Strange items do not change their name as they rank up (the rank is instead displayed as a subtitle under the name).

For an example, here's my renamed Vintage Flare Gun in TF2's backpack view (with quality colors turned on):

[image]